# How do I set up a very simple deployment using a Gitlab CI runner?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'd like to automatically deploy new work from my Gitlab repository to a live website running on a production server. The live website is a GIT repo clone of the `live` branch.

My questions:

- each time a 'build' happens, the runner seems to clone my repo afresh, into `~/builds/...`. Is this mandatory behaviour? All I think I really want is a `git pull` inside my production website directory.
- if it really has to clone the repo each time, why doesn't it `git reset` it? At least that would save a ton of bandwidth over time, wouldn't it?
- how do I run my `deploy.sh` which is in the repository root? I currently get this error in my gitlab.com builds info: `bash: line 23: deploy.sh: command not found`

My `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
deploy_to_production:
  script:
    - deploy.sh
  only:
    - live
  tags:
    - prod
```

#### Details

To do this, I want to run a simple shell script that I wrote (`deploy.sh`) on the production server, whenever I push to a specific branch of my repo (the `live` branch, in my case). This shell script is in my GIT repository, alongside my `.gitlab-ci.yml`.

The script basically just does a `git reset`, `fetch` and `pull`, bringing the production version up to date with what's in the repository.

I have installed a "shell" multi-runner on my server, and connected that to gitlab.com, where I can see it active.

Overall, I am barking up the wrong tree? Should I change my `deploy.sh` so that it doesn't do a git checkout of the new work, but rather uses `cp` or perhaps `rsync` to move the new code from `~/builds/...` into the production website?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Q: Is the cloning a mandatory behavior?**

As far as I know it is because the assumption is that during the build process you work with the code.

If that's not your case and you only want to "tell the production server" to pull the code from your repo, then maybe you can take a different approach and use a [webhook](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html) instead. GitLab would make a HTTP request to your server and pass the information about the event (push, merge, etc.) in the JSON format. The receiving script would then parse it and make a decision whether to do the git pull.

If you do have other tasks to perform on the code during the build process before deployment, then yes, alter the strategy and use the code that the runner has already checked out for you. I'd probably attempt to have the change **atomic** in some way (rsyncing into the live directory would leave your application in some uncertain state when it runs and in a mess if it fails for some reason), e.g. by having the live code in a directory that is symlinked. The deployment script would then copy the new code directory to its final destination, make any necessary adjustments and change the symlink's target from the old live directory to the new one.

**Q: If it really has to clone the repo each time, why doesn't it git reset it?**

That's more of a question for the developers. Anybody else's answer would be just speculation.

**Q: How do I run my deploy.sh which is in the repository root?**

If the *deploy.sh* script has the executable bit set, then use `./deploy.sh`, otherwise `bash deploy.sh`.

Comment: I will add, re "why doesn't it `git reset` it" — I noticed in Gitlab's project > settings > project settings area, under "Builds", that you can choose between `git clone` or `git fetch`. So you can choose whether you want a full fresh checkout for each build, or to just pull in the recent changes.

Comment: I've decided to copy the code from the build checkout, and switch a symlink like you suggested. That saves me from having to write and maintain a small custom nodejs server listening for webhook pings.

Comment: Hi, it seems that your `webhook` link points to some intranet resource...