# gitlab runner hard reset

Tags: django, shell, gitlab, runner

I am using `gitlab-runner` with `shell` executor. Every time I deploy with new source `media` files will be wiped out because `runner` will do `hard-reset` on my directory.

I have check the documents, but it does not mention about this mechanics

**Question:**
How do I let `runner` just ignore whatever in the `media` directory rather than do `hard-reset` and my files all are gone?

Comment: This is not the supposed behavior. So I have the idea that you have installed something wrong.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thank you for your comment. I am checking with `gitlab` issue

Comment: It is behavior by design.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37244329/how-do-i-set-up-a-very-simple-deployment-using-a-gitlab-ci-runner?rq=1